# Removing ui elements from vimeo player

Tags: user-interface, vimeo

I want to create a simple player and remove some of the ui elements from the vimeo player, but whatever I try it doesn't work...

I have this code to load the data. At the "videoUrl" I set the params, but with no effect

But according to their documentary it should go
https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001494447-Using-Player-Parameters

```
<template>
  // <img :src="data.thumbnail_url" alt="" @click="startVideo"/>
  <div v-html="data.html" />
</template>

<script>
  mounted() {
    const videoUrl = `https://player.vimeo.com/video/${this.video_id}?
      title=0&
      byline=0&
      portrait=0`
    const requestUrl = `https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=${videoUrl}`

    this.$axios.get(requestUrl).then((response) => {
      this.data = response.data

      // I also tried to create the iFrame by myself and set the params again in the src but also without any effect.
      this.createIframe()
    })
  },
</script>
```

```
createIframe () {
  const el_iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  el_iframe.setAttribute('src', `
    https://player.vimeo.com/video/${this.video_id}?
      title=0&
      byline=0&
      portrait=0
   `)
  }
  this.$el.appendChild(el_iframe)
}
```

I also upgraded to a Pro account in case some of these customizations are only possible within that plan.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set this attributes the video owner have to check this toggle button
[image]

and if you like to write the attributes in a list style, the ampersand must be in front of the attribute and the question mark in the same line with the the video-id

```
this.el_iframe.setAttribute('src', 
  `https://player.vimeo.com/video/${this.video_id}?
    title=0
    &byline=0
    &portrait=0
`)
```